# Does a sessions length get extended at the beginning of the call, or at the end of a call?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Just for curiosity, if I have a session timeout of 20 minutes and the following happens:

1. A user access a website. Initial session timeout starts.
2. After one minute on the same page `$.post("/api/longrunningfuction", function() {
   alert("success");
   })` is called.
3. The post call takes ten minutes before returning (hopefully not realistic, just to help get my question across).

Would the remaining time now be:

1. 20 minutes due to the post call returning and extending the session?
2. 10 minutes (calling post extended the session, but its been 10 minutes for the post to return).
3. Other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583.aspx) for the session end event says that (emphasis mine)

> A session expires when the number of minutes specified by the `Timeout`
>   property passes without a request **being made** for the session.

Therefore there should be 10 minutes remaining.

I haven't seen the framework code, but the session duration is controlled by setting the authentication cookie duration on response. Therefore it seems logical that even though the new cookie is sent when your server-side code has *completed*, the new expiration time is calculated when the request is *received*. If 10 minutes pass between the time the expiration time is calculated and the time it is communicated back to the client, then that's 10 minutes worth of session that have been lost.

Answer (score 1):

Session extension works by rewriting the forms authentication cookie to the response. More specifically if you have enabled sliding expiration for your forms authentication (usually not recommended for security reasons), when a request is sent to the server, the forms authentication module intercepts this request at the **beginning** of the request, it decrypts the forms authentication cookie in order to extract the forms authentication ticket and modifies the expiration date of this ticket and adds the new cookie to the response. All this happens at the beginning of the request. This means that the session will be extended with 20 additional minutes (or whatever your timeout is defined) from that moment.

Then let's suppose that the entire request takes 10 minutes to complete before returning the response to the client (and respectively the refreshed forms authentication cookie). When the client receives this cookie, there will be 10 more minutes left for it to be valid.